# Modal View using UIHostingController and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewcontroller

I have used a UIHostingController to use a SwiftUI view in a ViewController. In that SwiftUI view I am using two Buttons, which should show a Modal SwiftUI view when they are pressed. 
Unfortunately if I press the button, the state variable changes, but no Modal View is shown.

For the button I used the following code:

```
Button(action: {
    self.showModal = true
    let impactLight = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    impactLight.impactOccurred()
    print("show: ", self.showModal)}) {
          Text("ZEIGE STRATEGIE")
               .foregroundColor(.black)
               .frame(width: 254, height: 37)
               .shadow(color: Color.white, radius: 8, x: -9, y: -9)
               .shadow(color: Color("neumorphismShadowBlack"), radius: 8, x: 9, y: 9)
               .padding(5)
               .background(Color("mainBackgroundColor"))
               .cornerRadius(20)
                }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
                    StrategyView()}
                       .shadow(color: Color.white, radius: 8, x: -9, y: -9)
                       .shadow(color: Color("neumorphismShadowBlack"), radius: 8, x: 9, y: 9)
```

And for the UIView I used the following code:

```
  let swiftUIView = RecognitionView(detectedDices: detectedDices)
  let uiView = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)

  uiView.view.frame = feedbackView.frame
  uiView.view.center = CGPoint(x: feedbackView.frame.size.width / 2, 
  y:feedbackView.frame.size.height / 2)
  feedbackView.addSubview(uiView.view)
```

If showModal is set to true at the beginning, the Modal View is shown, but it does not work, when the Modal View should be visible, when the button is pushed.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please add the code to present the modal. It should be something like `.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { ... }`.

Comment: This code is already added

Comment: @user9696308 Please post entire code, I am suspecting issue is with `NavigationView` related with `UIHostingController`. I was facing same issue, we can discuss further.